# Make a line based on ball movement in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

How would I make pygame draw a line when the ball is moved? Currently I have it so that when you use the arrows a big red ball with a black border move around the screen. What I want is to have the user press a button and then it basicly would like triger pygame to draw a line and then if the user presses that key again it would not draw anymore and then if they press a button it would clear it. I would like to incorparate into my current code. I have done resarch on pygame.draw and drawing in pygame with no luck.
Here's my current code:

```
import os,sys 
import pygame as pg


DIRECTDICT = {pg.K_LEFT  : (-1, 0),
          pg.K_RIGHT : ( 1, 0),
          pg.K_UP    : ( 0,-1),
          pg.K_DOWN  : ( 0, 1)}

class Player:

    def __init__(self,rect,speed):
          self.rect = pg.Rect(rect)
          self.speed = speed
          self.movement = [0,0]
          self.make_image()
    def make_image(self):

         self.image = pg.Surface((self.rect.size)).convert_alpha()
         self.image.fill((0,0,0,0))
         pg.draw.ellipse(self.image,(0,0,0),(1,1,self.rect.size[0]-2,self.rect.size[1]-2))
          pg.draw.ellipse(self.image,(255,0,0),(6,6,self.rect.size[0]-12,self.rect.size[1]-12))
    def update(self,Surf):

         self.rect.move_ip(self.movement)
    self.draw(Surf)
def draw(self,Surf):
    Surf.blit(self.image,self.rect)


def quit_game():

     pg.quit();sys.exit()

def game(Player):

    for event in pg.event.get():
          Player.movement = [0,0]
          keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
    if event.type == pg.QUIT or keys[pg.K_ESCAPE]:
         quit_game()
    for key in DIRECTDICT:
        if keys[key]:
            for i in (0,1):
                Player.movement[i] += DIRECTDICT[key][i]*Player.speed

def main(Surf,Player):

       game(Player) 
       Surf.fill((255,255,255)) 
       Player.update(Surf) 
       pg.display.update() 


if __name__ == "__main__":
      os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1' 
      Surface = pg.display.set_mode((500,500))
      pg.init()
      Myclock = pg.time.Clock() 
      Myplayer = Player((250,250,100,100),3)  
      while 1:
              main(Surface,Myplayer)  
              Myclock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to maintain a state which indicates if the line should be drawn or not. Also you'll need a list where you store the player positions so you can draw a line between the points.

```
import os,sys 
import pygame as pg


DIRECTDICT = {pg.K_LEFT  : (-1, 0),
          pg.K_RIGHT : ( 1, 0),
          pg.K_UP    : ( 0,-1),
          pg.K_DOWN  : ( 0, 1)}


class Player:

    def __init__(self,rect,speed):
          self.rect = pg.Rect(rect)
          self.speed = speed
          self.movement = [0,0]
          self.make_image()
    def make_image(self):

         self.image = pg.Surface((self.rect.size)).convert_alpha()
         self.image.fill((0,0,0,0))
         pg.draw.ellipse(self.image,(0,0,0),(1,1,self.rect.size[0]-2,self.rect.size[1]-2))
         pg.draw.ellipse(self.image,(255,0,0),(6,6,self.rect.size[0]-12,self.rect.size[1]-12))
    def update(self,Surf):

        self.rect.move_ip(self.movement)
        self.draw(Surf)
        
    def draw(self,Surf):
        Surf.blit(self.image,self.rect)


def quit_game():

     pg.quit();sys.exit()

state = 0
points = []
def game(Player):
    global state
    global points
    keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT or keys[pg.K_ESCAPE]:
            quit_game()
        ### change state when space is pressed
        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN and event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
            if state == 0:
                state = 1
            elif state == 1:
                state = 2
            else:
                ### clear the points list
                state = 0
                points = []
    Player.movement = [0,0]
    for key in DIRECTDICT:
        if keys[key]:
            for i in (0,1):
                Player.movement[i] += DIRECTDICT[key][i]*Player.speed

### helper method to get each element of a list and each previous element
def offset(iterable):
    prev = None
    for elem in iterable:
        yield prev, elem
        prev = elem
        
def main(Surf,Player):
       global state
       global points
       game(Player) 
       Surf.fill((255,255,255)) 
       Player.update(Surf) 
       ### in state 1, start "collecting" the player position
       if state == 1:
           points.append(Player.rect.center)
       ### in state 1 and 2, draw the line
       if state in (1, 2):
           for p1, p2 in offset(points):
                if p1 and p2:
                   pg.draw.line(Surf, (255,0,0), p1, p2)
       pg.display.update() 


if __name__ == "__main__":
      os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1' 
      Surface = pg.display.set_mode((500,500))
      pg.init()
      Myclock = pg.time.Clock() 
      Myplayer = Player((250,250,100,100),3)  
      while 1:
              main(Surface,Myplayer)  
              Myclock.tick(60)
```

[image]

*(P.S.: Your code/indentation is quite messy, and your question is not 100% clear, but you should get the idea nonetheless).*

Comment: yeah I know its kind of wired typing in code into stackoverflow

Comment: also is there a way to add a clear button so that when i click the spacebar again it doesnt totally clear it but just picks up the pen and then can resume again im going to play around with it but i thought id ask

Comment: Next time paste code, highlight it, then click the 'code' button above the textbox.